# Implicit animation of layer opacity doesn't animate on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

I'm really confused why this code works fine on 10.6 and 10.7, but on 10.8 there is no animation and the opacity value changes immediately. Self is a NSView subclass.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5]
                 forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
self.layer.opacity = 1.0;
self.labelFilename.layer.opacity = 1.0;
self.labelDate.layer.opacity = 1.0;
[CATransaction commit];
```

Conversely this code fails to animate on 10.6 but works fine on 10.7 and 10.8

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
theAnimation.duration = 0.5;
theAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"fadeUp"];
[self.labelFilename.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"fadeUpName"];
[self.labelDate.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"fadeUpDate"];
```

Comment: I have a very similar issue. Have you managed to figure out what caused this?

Comment: i am having similar and other issues with CAAnimation on 10.8 (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307632/nsimageview-layer-not-updating-before-during-animation). any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i got my animations back to work on 10.8 by ADDING the explicit animation, like so:

```
// added explicit animation
CABasicAnimation *animOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(pi,0,1,0);
transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 1.0f);
[animOut setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity]];
[animOut setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
[animOut setDuration:0.3f];
[[goingImageView layer] addAnimation:animOut forKey:nil];

// implicit animation code that worked before 10.8
[[goingImageView layer] setTransform:transform];
```